# How to send activation link to email in android app

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have to store the user details entered in a signUp form in mysql database. When the registration completes then i have to send a link to registered email for account activation. 
SignUp form developed in Android. how to send an activation link to mail. 
please help me anybody.
I am using mysql as a database and android app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not realise you could have MySQL on Android.

There is a JavaMail API you can use to send emails from an Android device.

You can find documentation and examples here:
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=144

You might need to tweak it a bit

After looking around a bit, I found this question has already been answered here : [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124)

Comment: Thanks for your response sir.. I am using mysql as backend in android.. I need send a link for account activation.. can u please tell me how can I send activation link to entered email?

Comment: JavaMail API is very usefull to me